# How to add Streetview function in my MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mkmapview

I'm looking to add Streetview function to my current iphone app maps I made with MKMapView.
Any idea how to do this?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you want to spend a long time mapping tiles onto a 3D world, you can give a link to the maps app, which lets the user choose Street View.

If you want an easy way to embed Street View, use the (fairly new) [Street View Image API,](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/) which returns static images for a location and heading (relative to the road):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false

[image]

Comment: Can i use google's map iOS SDK? What i found on its website is they do support Streetview but not sure how it pin annotations and user's current location will be marked?