# How to use Street View Image API in mapkit?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mapkit

I'm looking to add Street view image api to my current iphone app maps I made with MKMapView. Any idea how to do this?

Thx for helping,

Answer (score -1):

You can add street view in google maps. For more please refer below link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/streetview

Comment: ,that,s right ,i can add street view in google maps,but how i do this in mapkit,because you know that mapkit is ios...

Comment: yes ,but how i use street view in mapkit because my app already developed,so now i want on mapkit....

Comment: In that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522210/how-to-add-streetview-function-in-my-mkmapview  is better solution

Comment: ok ,i got this,,here another problem ,when i add -objc flag to linker ,than xocde giving  error:ld: framework not found Metal for architecture armv7